# I am trying to remove double quotes from "234521" and get the output as 234521 in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a CSV file in which the values are like this:

"12342","red","world"

For processing my code which is in java, I want the double quotes to be removed and assign it to a particular variable. Like this:

`String number = num.replaceAll("^\"|\"$","");`

Note:quotes will always be present in starting and in the end of the value.

But the output of number is "12342" instead of 12342. What should I write to replace those double quotes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a CSV parsing tool and specify double quotes as escape character.  You should not be handling this yourself.

Comment: If you already parsed the CSV you can try `Integer.parseInt("123456")` or `Integer.valueOf("123456")`. Both will throw an exception if the value can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: I concur with Tim. Doing correct parsing of arbitrary CSV data is *much* harder than you think. Unless this is purely for education, you shouldn't re-invent the wheel. Your wheel will be deficient, and a constant source of trouble.

Comment: I aggree with Tim. If in doubt, think of a line like `"He said \"I am your father\" to...","another value"`.

Comment: I can't use a CSV parsing tool. It has to be done through code only. In the backend that particular value is String so we don't need to parse it. I just want to replace the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String number = num.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsDigit}\\p{IsAlphabetic}.,]", "");
```

This will work with all Strings regardless they're numbers or just text. The `regex` replaces everything that's not a **Digit** nor **Alphabetic**, so will remove the quotes from the CSV fields. Doesn't remove `.` or `,` neither.

---

Alternative should be, for just the quotes:

```
String number = num.replace("\"", "");
```

You'd need the backslash `\` to escape the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The below regular expression can also be used.

`String number= num.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");`

Comment: I used this expression but it's not working. Do you have any other method in your mind?